# Why is the PP, according to this derivation, directly moved from the lower (farther) DP, not the nearer one?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, movement, derivation

The sentence being parsed:

De CHOMSKY varios libros han ganado premios internacionales, no de Trotsky.

of Chomsky several books have won awards international-PL, not of Trotsky

[image]

Why is the PP on top *de Chomsky*, directly moved from the DP under *v**P,  as opposed to done in two hops: first the entire DP moves from Spec(*v**P) up to Spec (TP), and then C probes into Spec(TP) and extracts the PP and finally places it in Spec (CP)?

Much obliged to the kind souls of the syntacticians who are willing to help me out!

Comment: I fixed the italics in ‘*v*\*P’ – have a look to see if it looks right to you now.

Comment: The example is taken from a paper by Angel L. Jiménez-Fernández https://wuwr.pl/awr/article/download/153/132/

Comment: I disagree with this long movement analysis. And the tree itself is rather unconventional. You should ask the author of that paper.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Looks great! I messed up the italics and asterisks so bad. Thank you for helping me fix it!

Comment: @AlexB. Could you clarify whether you disagree with my view that the movement is done in two hops or you disagree with the author's view that the PP is directly extracted from the lower DP?

Comment: Disagree with the direct extraction. Imho you should ask the author

Comment: I agree with Alex B. It seems distinctly odd to extract the PP directly from its initial position like that; I would expect it to be analyzed as moving in two hops.